# Method for removing directory throws exception "The parameter is incorrect"

Tags: c#, winapi

I use this method in console application to delete folder created at the start of application:

```
private static void RemoveTempFolder()
    {
        if (Directory.Exists(TempFilesFullPath))
        {
            Directory.Delete(TempFilesFullPath, true);
        }
    }
```

And sometimes I get this exception when this method is executed:

> "System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The parameter is
>   incorrect"

What's wrong?

Comment: [`Directory.Delete`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fxeahc5f%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) doesn't throw `Win32Exception`. Are you sure this exception is thrown on this line?

Comment: Exception is thrown on production environment and logs show the line where RemoveTempFolder() method is executed.

Comment: It has to be something else. @Soner is right, `Directory.Delete` doesn't throw `Win32Exception`. Your issue is something else.